# Browser extension opens a window. Can I click a button in that window using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, applescript, browser-extension, duckduckgo, duckduckgo-api

The [DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials browser extension](https://help.duckduckgo.com/duckduckgo-help-pages/desktop/adding-duckduckgo-to-your-browser/) opens this window when clicked:

[image]

I want to programmatically click the `Generate Private Duck Address`-button. Can this be done? I probably first need to click the extension icon in the browser's menu bar? Clicking the Generate… button inserts a new Duck-address in the clipboard, where it is easy to access it.

Context: I am scripting a browser (probably Chrome) using AppleScript and need to generate Duck-addresses in/for my Applescript. Applescriptable browsers have a command along the lines `do Javascript` which sends a Javascript that is executed by the browser. An example of how it can look:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);" -- Jumps to the end of the page
end tell
```

(This example is slightly simplified)

I have googled this but mostly find results related to creating browser extensions or communicating between extension and web page.

**The whole question boils down to: how do I generate a new Duck-address and insert it into the computer's clipboard?** If there are other solutions than clicking the extension and then clicking this button, e.g., using DuckDuckGo's API, I am of course interested in them too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using their API.
Example in curl:

```
curl 'https://quack.duckduckgo.com/api/email/addresses' -X POST -H 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN' -H 'content-type: application/json'
```

You can use this script to get your access token:

```
curl -sSL https://codeberg.org/timedin/duckemail-token/raw/branch/main/src/shell/create_token.sh | bash
```